# Running a repetitive task with tk in perl

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have task that needs to be continuously performed through gui in perl.

The setup consists of a text field, a button and text area. When the button is pressed, the values in the text field are used by a system command to run repeatedly and the output displayed in the text area.

For example consider the following code:
use Tk;

```
# Main Window
my $mw = new MainWindow;

#GUI Building Area
my $frm_name = $mw -> Frame();
my $lab = $frm_name -> Label(-text=>"Command");
my $ent = $frm_name -> Entry();

#Button and command
my $ent = $mw -> Entry() -> pack();

my $but = $mw -> Button(-text=>"Run Command", -command =>\&push_button) -> pack();

#Text Area
my $textarea = $mw -> Frame();
my $txt = $textarea -> Text(-width=>40, -height=>10) -> pack();

#Geometry Management
$lab -> grid(-row=>1,-column=>1);
$ent -> grid(-row=>2,-column=>1);
$frm_name -> grid(-row=>1,-column=>1,-rowspan=>2);


$but -> grid(-row=>1,-column=>1,-columnspan=>1);

$txt -> grid(-row=>1,-column=>1);
$textarea -> grid(-row=>5,-column=>1,-columnspan=>2);

MainLoop;


## Functions
#This function will be executed when the button is pushed

sub push_button {
    my $name = $ent -> get();
    @out = qx($name);
    $txt -> insert('end', @out);
}
```

Now, what I want to do, is make it so that the push_button() sub runs every 30 s or so and prints the output in the text field.

I have looked into the repeat() function but was unable to run it properly. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

See [Tk::after](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/pod/after.pod).

For example, to repeat `push_button()` execution every 30 seconds:

```
$id = $widget->repeat(30 * 1000, \&push_button);
```